# How to automate Oracle add partition in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have begun to work on a new DWH system on Oracle 11g. I don't know application architecture and I would like to know.

I found which tables has partition on year of 2023. I found many tables many of them not interval partitioning.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.table_name)  
FROM dba_TAB_PARTITIONS a 
WHERE table_owner NOT IN (SELECT name 
                          FROM system.logstdby$skip_support 
                          WHERE action = 0) 
  AND partition_name LIKE '%2023%';
```

I need a procedure what it will check all user tables like hourly, daily, monthly partition and exists partition belong to which tablespace. After that it will create new necessarily partitions except of sys,sysaux etc schemas.

For example below procedure but I cannot fix it.For it will check partition is daily or monthly.

Can someone please guide me to automatize this procedure for scheduler job for create missing necessarily partition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_MISSING_PARTITIONS_FOR_ALL_TABLES AS
    v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30);
    v_table_name  VARCHAR2(30);
    v_partition_col VARCHAR2(30) := 'DATE_COLUMN'; -- 
    v_next_partition_date DATE;
    v_last_partition_name VARCHAR2(30);
    v_last_tablespace VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN (SELECT owner, table_name
                      FROM all_tables
                      WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'DBSNMP', 'OUTLN', 'SYSMAN')) LOOP
        v_table_owner := table_rec.owner;
        v_table_name := table_rec.table_name;

        SELECT MAX(partition_name), tablespace_name
        INTO v_last_partition_name, v_last_tablespace
        FROM all_tab_partitions
        WHERE table_name = v_table_name AND table_owner = v_table_owner;

        FOR i IN 1..12 LOOP
            v_next_partition_date := ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), i);

            DECLARE
                v_new_partition_name VARCHAR2(30);
                v_new_tablespace VARCHAR2(30);
            BEGIN
                v_new_partition_name := 'P'|| TO_CHAR(v_next_partition_date, 'YYYYMM');
                v_new_tablespace := v_last_tablespace; -- Son tablespace'ten alıyoruz
            END;

            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                          FROM all_tab_partitions
                          WHERE table_name = v_table_name
                          AND table_owner = v_table_owner
                          AND partition_name = v_new_partition_name) THEN
                -- Yeni partition'ı ekliyoruz
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || v_table_owner || '.' || v_table_name ||
                                  ' ADD PARTITION ' || v_new_partition_name ||
                                  ' VALUES LESS THAN (''' || TO_CHAR(v_next_partition_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''') TABLESPACE ' || v_new_tablespace;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Partition added for ' || v_table_owner || '.' || v_table_name || ': ' || v_new_partition_name);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END FOR;
END ADD_MISSING_PARTITIONS_FOR_ALL_TABLES;
/
```

Comment: A NEW DWH on 11g? it is out of support

Comment: no dwh is not new. I am new on company thatswhy I am trying to understand architecture

Comment: In any case, you should not count on the fact that existing partitions have the upper limit in the name. And you're declaring v_new_partition_name in a block and using it out of the block. And when you say 'I cannot fix it', tell us what problem you have with it. We cannot guess if that's a compilation error (the case here probably) or an execution error.

Comment: Many of us DBAs have written similar packages, but they are several pages long and require config tables to specify rules (what the granularity of the partition is, what datatype the key is, how to convert non-dates into dates, how far ahead to create them, what pattern to use to determine the new partition names, what tablespace to put it in, etc..). Plus you must conver the `high_value` long to varchar2 and then evaluate it to the proper datatype in order to test partition age, determine whether to add or split, etc.. This is not a trivial programming exercise.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just convert them to interval partitioning?